# How to recognize SSD drive with Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller in 'RAID mode'

Tags: drivers, ssd, sata, dmraid, ahci

I have a **Dell Latitude 5300** with a **SSD** drive and with what *lshw* shows as ''**82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]**''. BIOS is configured by default with **SATA operation** = "***RAID On***" mode and I don't want to change it to *AHCI mode*.

When booting from Ubuntu with USB it doesn't show any disk. If I switch BIOS to AHCI it really can see the disk, but as said I need to make it work in *RAID On mode*.

When I run "*sudo lshw -C storage*" this is what I get:

```
  *-storage
       description: RAID bus controller
       product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 30
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: storage msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:912b0000-912b7fff memory:912cb000-912cb0ff ioport:3090(size=8) ioport:3080(size=4) ioport:3060(size=32) memory:91200000-9127ffff
```

*dmesg* shows:

```
[    5.869019] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    5.870693] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 1 remapped NVMe devices.
[    5.870694] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.
```

Is there any way to make it work without switching to *AHCI mode*?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I have the same issue with a Dell G5. `lshw` shows device as `*-raid` type with `description: RAID bus controller` and `product: Intel Corporation`. Same `dmesg` message.